# Force State to Maintain Boolean Value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a banner that has it's visibility determined by the state of true or false. I have a close button with a clickHandler to set state to false, which hides the banner. When I navigate to a different page, the state resets to true, therefore the banner is visible.

How do I force the state to remain false, even if page refreshes or changes? Basically, I want the banner to not appear again, if the user closes it.

Note: Banner component is used a Layout component, which is used by all pages.

```
const BannerWrapper = styled.div`
  visibility: ${props => (props.show ? "visible" : "hidden")};
`

const CloseIcon = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
`

const Banner = () => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(true)

  const handleClick = () => {
    setShow(false)
  }

  return (
    <BannerWrapper show={show}>
      Some Banner Content
       <CloseIcon onClick={handleClick}>
        X
      </CloseIcon>
    </BannerWrapper>
  )
}

export default Banner
```

Comment: This banner should be present only in a specific route?

Comment: you have to manage state in a parent elem(like app.js). Cuz everytime the page where this component is rendered the default value will be true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can persist the state to localStorage. Use a state initializer function to read in the state when the component mounts, and an `useEffect` hook to save/persist state updates to storage.

```
const Banner = () => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(() => {
    const showBanner = localStorage.getItem('showBanner');
    // if showBanner null/undefined fallback to true
    return JSON.parse(showBanner) ?? true;
  });

  React.useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('showBanner', JSON.stringify(show));
  }, [show]);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setShow(false);
  };

  return (
    <BannerWrapper show={show}>
      Some Banner Content
       <CloseIcon onClick={handleClick}>
        X
      </CloseIcon>
    </BannerWrapper>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit force-state-to-maintain-boolean-value]

## Update - To "reset" and display banner.

If you want/need to reset to once again display the banner then I believe any of the following will do the trick:

- Remove it from localStorage: `localStorage.removeItem('showBanner');`
- Set it true: `localStorage.setItem('showBanner', JSON.stringify(true));`
- Set it null: `localStorage.setItem('showBanner', null);`

IMO removing it from localStorage is the cleanest option.

You could OFC also update the `show` state locally:

```
const enableBanner = () => setShow(true);
```

This will update the state and trigger the effect to persist the updated state value.

Comment: I think OP wants to have banner open initially...I think you should read value from localStorage as initial value of `useState`(if it is not undefined)

Comment: You could also put logic of first `useEffect` inside `useState` instead, but it is up to you :)

Comment: @gmoniava Right, good call, was doing that as you made second comment. :)

Comment: I like this idea, however it doesn't appear to be working. I do see in local storage, `showBanner` initiates as `true` and after closing, it changes to `false` and maintains that `false` value, however the banner still shows up?

Comment: @EricNguyen I didn't think it would matter with a plain boolean value, but the values going to localStorage still need to be JSON serialized. I updated my answer and included a running codesandbox. Sorry for any confusion and delay.

Comment: Very nice @DrewReese If I ever need to update that localStorage value `showBanner` back to true, what's the best approach of doing so?

Comment: @EricNguyen I updated my answer with some options for toggling back on the banner.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the question of "how do I persist values across page refresh" is: use local storage. There are hooks that implement the same kind of interface of `useState`, but store the value in the local storage instead of in memory under the hood.
One of those is `useLocalStorage` ( https://usehooks.com/useLocalStorage/ ).